# Laravel empty database gives SQLSTATE[42S02] error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I'm trying to migrate my database to an empty database,
but I get the following error when I do `php artisan migrate`:

```
  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'portal-for-fun.permissions' doesn't exist (SQL: select *
   from `permissions`)



  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'portal-for-fun.permissions' doesn't exist
```

All migrations can be found here: https://github.com/cskiwi/portal-for-fun/tree/master/database

but I think the problem lies here:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateRolesTables extends Migration {
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up() {
        Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('label')->nullable();
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
        });

        Schema::create('permissions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('label')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::create('permission_role', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('permission_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('permission_id')->references('id')->on('permissions')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->primary(['permission_id', 'role_id']);
        });


        Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->primary(['role_id', 'user_id']);
        });

        Schema::create('permission_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('permission_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('permission_id')->references('id')->on('permissions')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->primary(['permission_id', 'user_id']);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down() {
        Schema::dropIfExists('permission_user');
        Schema::dropIfExists('role_user');
        Schema::dropIfExists('permission_role');

        Schema::dropIfExists('permissions');
        Schema::dropIfExists('roles');
    }
}
```

the database itself only contains an empty `migration` table

Comment: if my answer was helpful, please choose my answer as best answer and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Create `permission` model in your project.
If you have `permission` model make sure that name in `permission` not `Permission`

Comment: Removing that isn't solving the issue

Comment: con you migrate rollback?

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problem. Try to seaprate migrations and move part of them (those which use `permissions` table) from `migrations` folder. First, you should run migration which will create `permissions` table with `php artisan migrate`. Then move back migrations which create `permission_role` and `permission_user` tables to the `migrations` folder and run `php artisan migrate` again.

That helped me, hope it'll help you too.